# How to debug Core Data Unresolved error (null), (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

When I try to save in Core Data I'm getting in the console:

> Unresolved error (null), (null)

```
- (void)saveInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {

    if (context == nil) {

        // Use default MOC
        context = self.managedObjectContext;

        NSError *error = nil;

        if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error])
        {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
             */
            DLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

    }
}
```

It's kind of hard to debug this when `NSError` object is `nil`.

What can I do to get more useful information why the save operation is not successful?

Comment: That is indeed strange. Is it reproducible? Does it occur on the device or in the Simulator?

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, it happens both on simulator and device and it's reproducible.

Comment: Just some ideas: 1) Set the `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` launch argument to enable debugging output. - 2) Check the system messages (if running in the Simulator).

Comment: @MartinR turning on the debugging didn't give away any "tasty" details for me, nothing that can lead me to why the saving is not working. What else can I try? I've tried deleting the app, cleaning, resetting simulator, restarting Xcode/Simulator.

Comment: The last resort would be a "system call trace": `dtruss -p <pid>` (as root), with the pid of the app running in the Simulator (use `ps -ef | grep <YourAppName>` to find the pid). There will be a lot of output, but if you have luck then you find some failed system call that points you into the right direction.